# mysql give different result if I download it

Tags: php, mysql, file, download

I am using PHP and MySQL to run a query, I have written two scripts having same query, but one for displaying the query result on browser and other for downloading the query result as a file. Even though its the same query, its giving different result while downloading, which is incorrect. 
My query for instance is

```
$query="select * from tf where gene_symbol like '%$sterm%' || gene_name like '%$sterm%' || synonym like '%$sterm%'";
```

If `$sterm` is **ZINC FINGER PROTEIN**, it give 685 records both on mysql command line and display. But if I download the file it give around 800 records by adding even the records `where gene_name like '%ZINC FINGER%'`

Does anyone have any idea, what could be causing it. 
Thanks in advance.
Konika

Here is the code for downloading the file

```
<?php

$sterm = $_POST["sterm"];
$sterm = strtoupper($sterm);
$query = "select * from tf where gene_symbol like '%$sterm%' || gene_name like '%$sterm%' || synonym like '%$sterm%'";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    result_disp($result);
}

function result_disp($results)
{
    $num_fields = mysql_num_fields($results);
    $headers    = array();
    for ($i = 0; $i < $num_fields; $i++) {
        $headers[] = mysql_field_name($results, $i);
    }
    $fp = fopen('php://output', 'w');

    if ($fp && $results) {
        header('Content-Type: text/csv');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="export.txt"');
        header('Pragma: no-cache');
        header('Expires: 0');
        fputcsv($fp, $headers, chr(9));
        while ($rows = mysql_fetch_row($results)) {
            fputcsv($fp, array_values($rows), chr(9));
        }
        die;
    }
}
fclose($fp);
?>
```

Comment: Are you using exactly the same SQL query in both files? Without the extra like clauses?

Comment: make sure `$sterm` is what you expect it is.

Comment: modify your query.. `$query="select * from tf where gene_symbol like '%".$sterm."%' || gene_name like '".%$sterm%."' || synonym like '".%$sterm%."'";`

Comment: @ Husman- I am using exactly the same query in both scripts. @ Do Sapr Kot- the variable remains same too @ Suhel Meman I will try it

Comment: I tried this $query="select * from tf where gene_symbol like '%"."$sterm"."%' || gene_name like '%"."$sterm"."%' || synonym like '%"."$sterm"."%'";   but it had no effect. Any other ideas??  Can I print the query in the same file somehow and see what $sterm is being used ?

Answer (score 1):

I think I fixed it, 
First removed the file download part and just printed the query on screen.
I saw that the variable got truncated from 'Zinc finger protein' to 'zinc'. Something in the post method I guess. Then I used single quotes on $sterm while passing it in post method 
like **value= '$sterm'** and it worked. here is the script I used to pass the variable :

```
echo "<table width='100%'><tr><td><strong>Click on column headers to sort; * dbTF = DNA binding Transcription Factor</strong></td> <td> 
<form action='search/download-search' method='post' >
<input type='hidden' name='sterm' value= '$sterm' >
<input type='submit' value='Download now'>
</form>
</td> </tr>
</table>";
```

How stupid of me to think - one query is giving different results :(
Thanks for your suggestion !